# Laravel - Display number of articles with a specific tag

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following foreach loop that outputs all the tag names:

```
<section class="popular-tags-section">
    <ul class="popular-tags-listings">
        @foreach($tags as $tag)  
          <li><a href="">{{ $tag->tag }}(3)</a></li>
        @endForEach   
    </ul>
</section>
```

The above code gives me the following in the frontend:

[image: tags]

Now instead of the `3` which is as of now a static number, i would like to display the number of articles with that given tag.

So of now my database is such that the `blog articles` are stored in separate table and the `tags` are stored in a separate table. The `blog articles` table has a column called `tag` and the `tags` table has a column called `tag` too. Now both of these tables are passed to the view in the form of the variables:

```
$recentPost // Contains all the blog articles
$tag // Contains all the tags
```

Now how do i display dynamically the number of articles that are tagged `javascript` for example ?

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

Blog Articles table:

[image]

Tags Table:

[image]

Homepage Code:

```
class PagesController extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        // Grap the latest post .. the last 10 :)
        $recentPost = Admin::orderBy('created_at' , 'desc')->take(10)->get();
        $tags = Tags::all();;
        return view('pages.index')->with('recentPost' , $recentPost)->with('tags' , $tags );
    }

}
```

Blog articles Modal:

```
class Admin extends Model {

    public $table = "admin";
    // public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'description',
        'keywords',
        'blog_content',
        'tag',
        'slug',
        'filePath'
    ];

}
```

Tags Modal:

```
class Tags extends Model {
    public $table = "tags";
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['tag'];
}
```

Comment: "The `blog articles` table has a column called `tag`" - You mean `tag_id` right?

Comment: It would be great if you show your models as well and table structure more precisely.

Comment: @imrealashu edited Thanks :)

Comment: `Tag` model as well.

Comment: @imrealashu Done

Comment: Check my answer. I think this should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get tags with counted articles for every tag using [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models):

```
$tags = Tags::withCount('articles')->get();
```

> If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without actually loading them you may use the withCount method, which will place a `{relation}_count` column on your resulting models

Display number of articles for specified tag:

```
{{ $tag->tag }} ({{ $tag->articles_count }})
```

This will work with correctly defined `articles` relationship in the Tag model. The best choice is many-to-many here, so you must have a pivot table and `articles` relation defined like this:

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
}
```

Comment: so i believe to start with i will need to create a foreign key ? Maybe the `tag` field in the `Admin` table should reference the `ID` field in the `Tags` table ?

Comment: I don't know what structure do you want to use, it's your decision. But if you want to make code in my answer work, you need to define `hasMany()` (one-to-many) or `belongsToMany()` (many-to-many with pivot table) relation between Tag and Article models.

Comment: Sorry to be asking a silly question again , but can i have `hasMany()` or  `belongsToMany()` relationships in my models without the two tables being connected via foreign key ?

Comment: You can skip creating a constraint, but you still need a key for `hasMany()` and pivot table (which will have two keys) for `belongsToMany()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Tags extends Model {
public $table = "tags";
public $timestamps = false;
protected $fillable = ['tag'];

public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
}}
```

In you controller you'd do something like this.

```
Tag::withCount('posts')->get();
```

I'm not quite sure if it would do the work or not because I'm not quite sure of the structure. Just let me know if you're get any error.